# How to customize the custom options in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, extensions, custom-options

For example

In magento have added two custom options as Size(S,L,XL) and Color(RED,BLUE).

But in frontend i have to show the size as

[image: Size]

And color as

[image: Color]

Ideas welcome.

Comment: which type of product is this ? you add custom options as dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of extension in magento store(magento-conect), search by color swatch you may get some modules what you need,

eg,

some freemodules:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-1.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatch-1.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-colors.html

some paid modules:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-color-swatch.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatch-with-zoom.html

use what you like

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create classes using the color names and modify the filter labels to add that class (given the option name) and have a nice CSS behind that to display some nice squares.

As far as sizes are concerned, you could either do the same, or use custom font-icons.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed new module Option swatches that allow to display option swatches on product details page and product list page by replacing drop-down custom options or configurable product's options.

Check here http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2015/01/product-custom-option-pro-with-optionswatch.html

For Magento2: [Product Custom Option Swatches For Magento 2](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2019/01/product-custom-option-swatches-magento2.html)